# No-root Android Firewall with Ad Blocker (KitKat compatible)

Tags: android, firewall, ad-blocker, content-filtering

I'm looking for an Android app with the following features:

1. Does not require root
2. Acts a firewall (can use VPN)
3. Acts as a global ad-blocker, preferably with user-defined lists (similar to AdAway, but without requiring root)
4. Runs on KitKat devices

NetGuard meets all of these requirements, except the last one.

Prefer gratis and open-source, but open to all answers.

Unlike [this related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50460/no-root-android-ad-blocker-kit-kat-compatible), firewall functionality ***is*** needed.

Comment: If FOSS is not a requirement: looks like [Adguard](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardForAndroid) would fit your description. Full version [available via my repo](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.adguard.android). The one [at playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adguard.android.contentblocker) seems to be stripped. Should run from ICS up, so also matches #4. // let me know when this is acceptable (I'm not using it myself, so I'm not 100% sure) and I'll make up an answer.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy!  It looks great.  But the price is steep!  About 12 euros every year... no one time purchase available. :(

Comment: What? I must have missed that. If it's even paid software, I'll kick it out of my repo ASAP. Sorry to read that, and my apologies. But then I'm afraid there is no match to your request …

Comment: @Izzy No apology needed! :)  What about something that meets all requirements except #2, and is gratis or low-cost?  (I can post a separate question if there is a match.)

Comment: Have you checked with [my list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker)? My devices are all rooted, so I use AdAway and don't care about the rest. [DNS66](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.jak_linux.dns66/) might be worth a look. Oh, no: LP+ only. That means list empty. Not sure how well [Unbound for Android](https://github.com/smarek/android-unbound-dns) works (that's what i use on my Pi at home), but it seems no longer maintained.

Comment: @Izzy Let's chat about it.... https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78437/izzychat

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Close but not quite.  Requirements here are to also have a firewall and to work on KitKat.  DNS66, for example, will not work on KitKat.