# No-Root Android Ad Blocker (KitKat compatible)

Tags: android, ad-blocker, content-filtering

I'm looking for an Android app with the following features:

1. Does not require root
2. Acts as a global ad-blocker, preferably with user-defined lists (similar to AdAway, but without requiring root) - Can use ***local*** VPN.
3. Runs on KitKat devices

NetGuard meets all of these requirements, except the last one.

Prefer gratis and open-source, but open to all answers.

Unlike [this related question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50436/no-root-android-firewall-with-ad-blocker-kitkat-compatible), no firewall functionality is needed.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: @Mawg  Unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: I figured, as you would have posted if you did :-)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure how well it works, but there is a version of Adblock Plus that existed for Android. It is fairly outdated, so it should run on KitKat. It works only on WiFi without root. It is no longer linked to on their website, but here it is:
https://downloads.adblockplus.org/adblockplusandroid-1.3.apk

http://web.archive.org/web/20170207164041/https://adblockplus.org/en/android-install

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had seen that, and was thinking about taking a look.  I didn't realize it only works on WiFi (without root).  That sort of disqualifies it, but thank you for mentioning that important detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another option. I haven’t tried it, but it’s open source. It appears that while the current version doesn’t support KitKat, and older version that’s still available does.

https://blokada.org/#download